# I'm unable to register my model in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-admin

My code is working as expected but my model is not getting registered.
This is my model class : **create_models.py (model class)**

```
*from django.db import models
    class UserModel(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default='')
        email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default='')
        #phone = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default='')
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True, default='')
        company = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
        class Meta:
            ordering = ('id',)*
```

This is my admin class: **register_admin.py (admin class)**

```
*from django.contrib import admin
from core.models.create_models import UserModel
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(UserModel)*
```

I ran commands :

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Still, the I'm unable to register the model.
[image: no model on server]

from apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'core'
```

from settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'core.apps.CoreConfig',
    'corsheaders',
]
```

[image: directory structure]
[image: directory structure]

Comment: have you tried to restart django yet? also why your files not name models.py and admin.py, check if your app is registered in settings yet?

Answer (score 0):

1. Registered the class in the admin.py file:

```
admin.site.register(UserModel)
```

2. Check App Installed

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
        ...,
        ...,
        'UserModel',
        ...,

)
```

3. Try Creating A new Super User

   ```
   python manage.py createsuperuser
   ```

Comment: I'm getting the below error if I register UserModel.
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")

django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Comment: I have shared the app.py and settings.py code along with the directory structure. could you please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this though Above ans is already convincing

```
@admin.register(UserModel)
class UserModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display = ('name','email',#blabla)
```

and try creating super user and reload your server